# Xcode Workflow Setup and Tips and Tricks

Tags: xcode, workflow

So I'm attempting to find a workflow to utilize Xcode. Something that was part of my workflow was to print out the data I was working with, so as to visualize the data and check my assumptions. Xcode doesn't offer an obvious way to quickly print out data that I'm aware of to visualize data, though I think the app preview visualizing feature is a very helpful feature - online videos have suggested printing Data structures in Playgrounds, but that would be data outside of the context of an app. So who can recommend a set of debugging workflows, tips and tricks, shortcuts, testing practices to make writing in Xcode more enjoyable?

I briefly searched some online videos, a few of which suggested printing in Playgrounds.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? If just debug printing in console, it can be done in Xcode as well, not just Playgrounds. As for other "tips and tricks," Apple's docs could be a good starting point: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/debugging.